# Category block has DISPLAY:none - Prestashop

Tags: javascript, css, categories, prestashop, displaytag

I have a problem, I don't know why, but my prestashoop categories stoped working. They just dissapeared.

I've checked the code and in some magical way the `display:none` is applied to the element.

How can I track what applied it? How can I fix it (not CSS overwrite, with !important).

Heres the page: [Growmundocannabico.com](http://www.growmundocannabico.com)

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

possible solution 1: try clearing the /tools/smarty/cache folder

possible solution 2: you have a javascript error:

```
ReferenceError: HoverWatcher is not defined
[Break On This Error]   

var cart_block = new HoverWatcher('#cart_block');
```

in your ajax-cart.js file. Try disabling the ajax cart, if it works, then fix your error in ajax-cart.js

Comment: Yes, I've noticed the error, any ideas how to fix? I'm green in JS.

Comment: Know it is clear, that this error causes the problem, because I've disable the ajax option in cart and categories appeared. 

Do you mean no clean this folder: cache/smarty/cache , because one you've mentioned don't exist in my directory.

Comment: yes, that's the folder. 
about the solving your js issue.... might take a litle longer

Comment: first try commenting lines 654 and 655 in your ajax-cart.js file. the cart should continue working. if it doesn't hide on loading, put a default display:none on it from css

Comment: ok, no worries, Solved, I've replaced the Ajax-cart.js with default one, because I was experimenting there. After I've cleared the cache folder's it works as a charm. Any ideas why my new item images may be missing?

Comment: can you see them in admin area? if yes, 1. try to regenerate the thumbnails, 2. try to regenerate your .htaccess file

Comment: Regenerated thumbnail's, didn't work. How to regenarate the htaccess file?? Here is the more info about this problem: http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/237866-new-item-images-missing/

Comment: Regenerated htacces by trigering the friendly CEO then regenerated the images, still, no effect...

Comment: one more possible issue, but that from the server configuration. are your images using uppercase extension? (like .JPG), if yes, rename and reupload

Comment: hi, I will try to reupload, but here is the route of the image: http://www.growmundocannabico.com/img/p/14-654.jpg lowercase .jpg :) Also I've noticed, that the photos don't appear only in featured items module. Inside the description image apears. I tryed reinstaling the module, but it didn't help.

Comment: Fixed it :) The image was defined wrong in 'homefeatured.tpl' changed it to the one I had in BO and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Without CSS overwrite it is not possible at least here because you have the code of prestashop not us. It is only accessible by external styles.

```
#categories_block_left .block_content .tree,#categories_block_left .block_content .dhtml{
display: block;
}
```

Comment: well, I don't know about that, if I make display:block, then all the categories appear. This is not what I'm after, because these has to be dynamic categories and have do expand/collapse when clicked.

Comment: ok, so go to the back end file edit there. No option is left if it should be dynamic